# how to access variable inside the closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Can some help on to read the variables inside the closures. I know by having a function with return statement i can get the value.

```
var getCounter = (function () {
    var counter = 10;
    return function () {return counter;}
})();

getCounter(); produces 10
```

Is there any way to access or read the variable without the return function ?

Comment: no... that is the whole purpose of closure variables

Comment: why do you want to do that

Comment: You can but why do you it ? Why have you introduced `closure` then ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, Just curious about to get the value in one our test cases. Also we are following best practices to go with closures for our work.

Comment: You can certainly define it global..But value will be updated if `closure` manipulates it..

Answer (score 1):

```
var getCounter = (function () {
    this.counter = 10;
})();

console.log(counter);
```

or

```
var getCounter = (function () {
        counter = 10;
    })();

    console.log(counter);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/768n5d2k/)

Comment: Well in this case, `this` belongs to `window`.. if OP wants to do it this way, then why `closure` ? Also note, `this` will fail in `"use strict";`

Comment: `var getCounter = (function () {
    this.counter = 10;
})();` This code will also produce the same result what is purpose writing `return function () {return counter;}` as getCounter is self-executing function where this refers to  `window`.

Comment: then ...dont use closure..Its close the purpose of the closure....or simply use counter...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you need a closure here,

```
var getCounter = (function () {
  counter = 10;
  return counter;
})();
// As you wrote a closure it is self executed so getCounter variable has the counter value; 
var x = getCounter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

```js
var counter;
var getCounter = (function() {
  counter = 10;
})();
```